# multiple daemon running for the same service in RHEL6

Tags: rhel, performance, cpu

I am using RHEL6.6 on VM. ControlMinder(CA) is installed there. Some of the vms I saw multiple seosd processes running. It causes high cpu usages by sys (using top) and decrease the performance of os and sometimes I can't login using ssh or vmrc. After rebooting or killing all the seosd, the vms come to normal state.

How can I protect multiple seosd daemon? Is it a bug of CA?